# Running jar file on Windows - Prompt user to download JRE

Tags: windows, java, jre

On OS X, when I try to run a `.jar` file, the system would ask me to download Java Runtime Engine if I don't have it installed, which makes sense.

However, on Microsoft Windows, that doesn't happen; I simply get a typical window message saying I don't have any program to open that kind of file.

Is there anyway to let the user know he needs to have the JRE, because otherwise the typical end-user won't understand how to handle it.

Comment: The proper way to handle this behavior is to create an installer which downloads and installs Java for the user  then installs your application.

Comment: I don't really want the user to install my app, since it's only a ``jar``file. And it must be very thin (less than 1mb) which does not allow me to have a full package along.

Comment: Without an installer what you won't won't be possible.  OS X handles .jar files differently then Windows out of the box.  Windows has no idea how to handle .jar files unless Java is installed.  The installer will solve that problem for you.

Comment: Related: [How to convert jar file into an exe which would run without requiring Java (JRE or JDK)?](http://superuser.com/q/900940/150988)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the user to "install" your app,
and you don't want to distribute a large package,
but, if you're willing to add a second file,
you can obtain the result you want
by distributing a `.bat` file with your `.jar`. 
A batch file can implement the behavior you describe:

- Check whether JRE is installed.

  - If if is, run the JAR.
  - If it isn't, display an informative message.

Comment: That does not fit my need since I can only send one file (jar). If I was able to use ``.bat`` files I was also able to use an ``.exe`` and put all behaviour there. But unfortunately exe/bat are considered dangerous and therefore email services like gmail will block them. Thanks